# Datalist options with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do a live search engine using AJAX. Now the code works correctly when performing searches and returning data that matches the string, but I'm currently stucked in what you could say is the dumbest part of the code.

The result of the search is being returned as a whole string when more than one string matches the searched string, instead of being parsed into separated options. Images will tell better the story

Here if I search for 'test', I get two results, but you can see they are being treated as only one result.

[image]

even though the response show it's treating it as two separated strings.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <h1>Ajax Live Search Test</h1>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.cfm" method="post">
    <div class="search-post-container">
        <div class="search-post-input">
            <input type="text" id="modelName" list="modelList" placeholder="&#xf002; Search..." required style="font-family: Arial, FontAwesome">
            <datalist id="modelList"></datalist>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        //Set delay var
        var delay = 2000;
        $('#modelName').keyup(function() {
            var model = $(this).val();
            if(model != '') {
                // Wait 2sec before sending another request.
                setTimeout(function (){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"index.cfc?method=ajaxSearchModel",
                        method:"GET",
                        dataType:"json",
                        data:{"model_name":model},
                        success:function (data) {
                            //This works, yet we still need address an issue
                            $("#modelList").empty();
                            $.each(data, function (index,item){
                                $("#modelList").append("<option value='" + item + "'></option>");
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }, delay);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I suspect the issue lies on this part of the code

```
$.each(data, function (index,item){
    $("#modelList").append("<option value='" + item + "'></option>");
});
```

My guess is that my code is purposely assigning all data into only one option, which would explain why the parsing is working correctly but all values are stored into only one option OR is something regarding the loop.

Thanks in advance and any tips on how to improve my code are always welcomed :)

EDIT:

Here's the index.cfc code

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="ajaxSearchModel" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="json" returntype="query">
        <cfargument name="model_name" type="string" required="no">

        <cfquery name="local.data">
            SELECT pr.post_model_name
            FROM postReview pr
            JOIN users u ON pr.user_id = u.user_id
            JOIN platforms p ON p.platform_id = pr.platform_id AND p.platform_name = pr.platform_name
            WHERE pr.post_model_name LIKE (REPLACE(<cfqueryparam value="%#Arguments.model_name#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">, ' ', '_'))
            ORDER BY pr.post_id
        </cfquery>

        <cfreturn local.data>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Please share code for index.cfc?method=ajaxSearchModel there is no issue with this code $.each(data, function (index,item){
    $("#modelList").append("<option value='" + item + "'></option>");
});

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vL31q0nw/

Comment: Added index.cfc code

Comment: The fiddle works as expected. When you inspect your DOM after the AJAX call is complete, what do you see? What happens when you log `data`?

Comment: sorry for adding this snippet here on the comment section

`{COLUMNS: Array(1), DATA: Array(2)}
      COLUMNS: Array(1)
         0: "POST_MODEL_NAME"
         length: 1
         [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
      DATA: Array(2)
         0: ['test']
         1: ['test']
         length: 2
         [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
      [[Prototype]]: Object`